# I can't get current url when I receive a external-login url with token

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to get current url in Angular 7 but I don't know how is getting only the first "/" of full url.

Comment: Do you want only to get the current url or to go to an url.
If you want to get the current url you can write something like this: `window.location.pathname`. or something like this `this.router.url === '/login'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.local.href`, split it on `/`.

Example

```js
const url = 'http://4200/external-login/gjoieoi89t74897yshfliuop';

console.log(url.split('/')[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, is working fine, that was really easy, jesus...!